# Best ways to read values from XML and validating XML schema

Tags: xml, automapper

I have an  xml and a class with properties.

using Automapper can we map values in XMl with properties inside a class. And can we do XML schema validation here along with reading values?

Answer (score 0):

Automapper is a object to object mapping utility. You cannot just use Xml to map to an object. If your class has the same properties as xml then you should deserializ the xml to that class object.

See this example.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fa420a9y(v=vs.110).aspx

And to validate xml you can build a stand xsd and validate against that.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162371(v=vs.110).aspx